# Overlaping options in Combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a problem with overlaping items in my Combobox. Data for this dropdown is taken from a table. Please refer to the screenshot below:

[image]

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: What is the font size of the combobox?

Comment: Font was settled be default 8, but when I change to 7 then everything is fine! Thank you for your help!

Comment: In my experience, it is best to set it at 10. Works well when you open the excel file in MAC as well :)

Comment: Did you define a scaling <> 100% in the Microsoft Windows display settings?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is related to **appropriate size of font** in our UserForm. Changing the font helped solve the issue.